# What is the variable "i" in loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw the following code in a coding challenge, I don't know why it returns 3, but check the code and tell me what do u think.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
for i in myList:
   i += 1
print(myList[-2])
```

When I saw the code I said it will print 4 because in the loop we added 1 in all integers in the list, and `[-2]` is supposed to give me the second-last value, which is 4 according to what I think.

I know I'm missing something here but I don't know what it is, so if anyone could explain this to me I'll appreciate it. Probably I'm not understanding `i`, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AaronJones `'current index of your list'` this is not true. `i` is the actual value.

Comment: Check out https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp#:~:text=A%20for%20loop%20is%20used,other%20object%2Dorientated%20programming%20languages.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Ah, my mistake, I forgot python is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Explanation***

The line:

```
for i in myList
```

Iterates over the ***items*** of the list `myList`, not it's indices.

The line in it that adds one `i += 1` doesn't assign the new value to the list, therefore is unchanged.

***How to Fix***

However, if we change the code to iterate over the indices:

```
for i in range(len(myList))
```

We can now change the values in the list:

```
myList[i] += 1
```

Code fix:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(myList)):
   myList[i] += 1

# 4
print(myList[-2])
```

***Some Advice***

It's a convenience in Python to name variables with lower-case, underscore separated names.

So `myList` would be `my_list`.

It doesn't change how the program behaves but would be more readable for your future teammates.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is ok, but note that the changed value is not stored back to the list replacing the original (the list remains unchanged!)

Answer (score 0):

The index of list is

```
    myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 +ve index    0  1  2  3
 -ve index   -4 -3 -2 -1
```

`i` is modified in that iteration and is not stored in list. Hence `myList[-2]` is `3`

Answer (score -1):

`i` is the current item of your list, `i` took the value but not is a reference, therefore is unchanged